# How to access the values of NSMutableDictionary in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

This is my code

```
NSMutableArray *responseArray = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
```

I want to do like this to get values:

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>];
```

I want to add `NSMutalbeArray` to Dict variable, how to do this please help me

This is the `responseArray`:

```
response >>>>>>>>> succ [{"id":"1","name":"Guitars \/

 Basses","description":"","image":"","parent_category":null},{"id":"2","name":"Keyboards \/ 

 Modules","description":"","image":"","parent_category":null},{"id" . . . . .  }]
```

How to get the dictionary values ?

Comment: You are question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

First check your json response on http://jsonlint.com/. It is **Invalid**.

Comment: NSMutableArray *responseArray = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
....
NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:[responseDict objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"cat_id"];
        [defaults synchronize];.....

Please Correct this Please

Comment: Is this your response: `[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Guitars Basses",
        "description": "",
        "image": "",
        "parent_category": null
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Keyboards Modules",
        "description": "",
        "image": "",
        "parent_category": null
    }
]`   . You have to parse this?

Comment: i have parsed this by this code :
NSMutableArray *responseArray = [responseString objectFromJSONString];

Comment: i want to do something like this---->>> dictionary *dict = ResponseArray.........how to do this ?

Comment: Try this code: `NSMutableArray *responseArray = [responseString objectFromJSONString];

for(int i = 0; i<[responseArray count]; i++){

NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:i];

NSString *strId = [responseDict objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *strName = [responseDict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *strDescription = [responseDict objectForKey:@"description"];
NSString *strImage = [responseDict objectForKey:@"image"];
NSString *strParent_category = [responseDict objectForKey:@"parent_category"];

}`. This may help you!